# Contenteditable loses focus after I modify its innerHTML, How do I make the caret position to the end of edited content?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I have already asked another question: [How to set caret position in a contenteditable after I append a span into it; and move caret to the end of the span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875208/how-to-set-caret-position-in-a-contenteditable-after-i-append-a-span-into-it-an)

My code adds the span tag and then modifies the innerHTML of the content editable element like;

```
contenteditable.innerHTML = newModifiedDataWithSpan;
```

but this causes my contenteditable to lose focus. If I use focus() on the element, the caret moves to the beginning of the contenteditable. Is there anyway to append a unicode character to the end my inputted span, and then search for said character, remove it and move caret to that position?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity)

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles sorry this just moves the cursor to the end of the contentEditable. I am trying to insert a span with a unicode character \u2006 at the end of it, and using range to delete it, so the cursor will appear there

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles thanks but I used another method detailed in my answer below